# Semantic UI Sidebar is not loading

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I am trying to code a locally saved simple web page. I have implemented the Semantic UI as the css framework. I am Trying to use a similar menu setup as one of their examples. I have the majority coded the same, yet when I click on the menu button the sidebar does not become visible.

```js
var sideBarMenu = $('ui.sidebar');

sideBarMenu
  .sidebar({
    context: $('.bottom.segment')
  })
  .sidebar('attach events', '.main .item', 'show');
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title></title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha512-8bHTC73gkZ7rZ7vpqUQThUDhqcNFyYi2xgDgPDHc+GXVGHXq+xPjynxIopALmOPqzo9JZj0k6OqqewdGO3EsrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js" integrity="sha512-dqw6X88iGgZlTsONxZK9ePmJEFrmHwpuMrsUChjAw1mRUhUITE5QU9pkcSox+ynfLhL15Sv2al5A0LVyDCmtUw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rye&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="SVGPCGen.css">
</head>

<div class="ui fixed main menu" id="menuButton">
  <a href="" class="launch icon item">
    <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="ui bottom attached segment pushable">
  <div class="ui inverted labeled icon left inline vertical sidebar menu">
    <a class="item" id="calculate">
      <i class="calculator icon"></i> Calculate
    </a>
    <a class="item" id="save">
      <i class="save icon"></i> Save
    </a>
    <a class="item" id="load">
      <i class="upload icon"></i> Load
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
```

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, found the problem was missing a class description in Javascript jquery search